# how to pass the executionContext on the Ribbon workbench for a HomePageGrid

Tags: dynamics-crm, executioncontext, crm-ribbon-workbench

I have been able to pass the formContext to the javascript function that I call from the ribbon when I call it from a Form button, but the same trick when calling from the HomePageGrid pass me a null value.

I use in both cases the Primary Control CRM parameter as stated in multiple places.

[image]

You can see on the left side how my PrimaryControl CRM parameter is passing a null value when selecting an item on the Grid. On the right side you can see how my PrimaryControl CRM parameter is passing the formContext correctly.

is it there any way to pass the executionContext/formContext/Context?. As you can see I have tried that is the Primary Control value is null to pick up Xrm.page.context and xrm.ui.getglobalContext.... and still doesn't work.

Any idea of what to do?

This is the configuration in the Ribbon Workbench
[image]

**Updated for minohimself:**

I have set the SelectedControl in the Ribbon and I am receiving on the first parameter the Mscrm.GridControl. And I dont see the formContext as you see it.

I might be doing something wrong, because it is obvious that you are able to see the context? can you point me in the right direction?

What I can see from your javascript code is that you have a theia.button which has a function called ExecuteActionWithErrorMessage that receives at least 4 parameters, including objectid, formContext, entityName, and actionName).

In my case my function is called and should receive the formContext and a yes/no (T/F) statement to decide how to manage the security roles.

So, should I include your four parameters, so I can retrieve as well the objectid, formcontext, entityname and actionname?

Thanks for your quick turn around and help.

[image: UPDATE for minohimself]

UPDATE 2:

Here you can see my Ribbon Workbench Command
[image: this is my Ribbon Workbench Command]

and here you can see my Debugger View:
[image: This is my Debugger View]

as you can see what you see it is not what I see. I am on a Ms. Dynamics CRM v9.0.15.9 (version 1612)  on-premises.

Comment: What do you need context for exactly?

Comment: Hi Guilermo, no you dont need four parameters. I just used one of my javascripts that was already used to quickly test it. Im sending ID and Selected control the other parmas are empty

Comment: I posted screenshot from all the parameters but you dont need them all just Selected control ;)

Comment: Homegrid has no formContext cause there is no form to load. Can you please explain why do you need formContext?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried SelectedControl parameter ? that one is ment for subgrids. The one youre using is used on Forms. ;)

[image]

I just tested what you get when you pass SelectedControl

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried with no luck. I can show image with results. :(

Comment: I have updated the answer with screenshot where i pass SelectedControl

Comment: minohimself, i have update my question as well with a screenshot, and it is passing mscrm.gridcontrol, not the formContext.

Comment: minohimself, quick question your code is running in the form or in the HomeGrid? I need my code to run in the HomeGrid (any given view of the opportunity entity in Dynamics CRM v9)

Comment: It's running in HomeGrid

Comment: On the entity Account

Comment: I don't get it.. why on my opportunity account it is not able to do the same... I got the MsCrm.GridControl which has neither formContext, nor ContextToken, nor ApplicationContext.
See Update 2

Comment: Can you please make a screenshot of you ribbon where you have the selectedControl ?

Comment: If you have teams we can have a look :) milan@theiasolutions.ch